# Find Word From a jumbled String

Tags: java

I have a scrambled String as follows: "artearardreardac".

I have a text file which contains English dictionary words close to 300,000 of them. I need to find the English words and be able to form a word as follows:

```
C A R D
A R E A
R E A R
D A R T
```

My intention was to initially loop through the scrambled String and make query to that text file each time n try to match 4 characters each time to see if its a valid word.

Problem with this is checking it against 300,000 words per loop.. Going to take ages. I looped through only the first letter 16 times and that itself take a significant time. The amount of possibilities coming from this method seems endless. Even if I dismiss the efficiency for now, I could end up finding English words which may not form a Word.

My guess is I have to resolve and find words while maintaining the letter formation correctly from the start somehow? At it for hours and gone from fun to frustration. Can I just get some guidance please. Looking for similar questions but found none.

**Note**: This is an example and I am trying to keep it open for a longer string or a square of different size. (The example is 4x4. The user can decide to go with a 5x5 square with a string of length 25).

**My Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String result = wordSquareCreator(4, "artearardreardac");
    System.out.println(result);
}


static String wordSquareCreator(int dimension, String letter){



    String sortedWord = "";
    String temp;

    int front = 0;
    int firstLetterFront = 0;
    int back = dimension;


    //Looping through first 4 letters and only changing the first letter 16 times to try a match.
    for (int j = 0; j < letter.length(); j++) {
        String a = letter.substring(firstLetterFront, j+1) + letter.substring(front+1, back);
        temp = readFile(dimension, a);
        if(temp != null){
            sortedWord+= temp;
        }
        firstLetterFront++;
    }

    return sortedWord;
}

static String readFile(int dimension, String word){
    //dict text file contains 300,00 English words
    File file = new File("dict.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String text;

        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(text.length() == dimension) {
                if(text.equals(word)){
                    //found a valid English word
                    return text;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(reader != null)
                reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can greatly cut down your search space if you organize your dictionary properly.  (Which can be done as you read it in, you don't need to modify the file on disk.)

Break it up into one list per word length, then sort each list.

Now, to reduce your search space--note that singletons can only occur on the diagonal from the top left to the bottom right.  You have an odd number of C, T, R and A--those 4 letters make up this diagonal.  (Note that you will not always be able to do this as they aren't guaranteed unique.)  Your search space is now one set of 4 with 4 options (24 options) and one set of 6 (720 options except there are duplicates that cut this down.)  17k possible boards and under 1k words (edit: I originally said 5k but you can restrict the space to words starting with the correct letter and since it's a sorted list you don't need to consider the others at all) to try and you're already under 20 million possibilities to examine.  You can cut this considerably by first filtering your word list to those that contain only the letters that are used.

At this point an exhaustive search isn't going to be prohibitive.

Comment: Thanks this has sparked the idea on reducing my time. But how am I going on to set up the square in this instance. Like I said even if I can put aside efficiency for now, I could be finding English words that may not make up the square. Or should I be handling this separately. Make the checks as you mentioned and store the reduced dictionary data in a List locally and perform nested loops to handle getting the square.

Comment: @jjanks Yes, reduce your lists as much as possible to reduce the search space.

Comment: To clarify, in the end I would still be doing multiple arranging of 4 words at a time till one arrangement works. such as Try 1: aa,bb,cc,dd. Try 2: bb,aa,cc,dd. Try 3: bb,cc,aa,dd and so on till none of this works and I throw aa and move on to introduce ee and carry on. Does this make sense.

Comment: I would place one word at a time.  Any path rejected before word 4 saves even testing some combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you want to create a word square out of those letters that you take in as a parameter to your function, you know that the absolute word length in your square is sqrt(amountOfLetters). In your examplecode that would be sqrt(16) = 4. You can also disqualify a lot of words directly from your dictionary:

1. discard a word if it does not start with a letter in your "alphabet" (i.e. "A", "C", "D", "E", "R", "T")
2. discard a word if it is not equal to your wordlength (i.e. 4)
3. discard a word if it has a letter not in your alphabet

The amount of words that you want to "write" in your square is wordlength * 2 (since the words can only start from the upper-row or from the left-column)

You *could* actually first start by going through your dictionary and copying only valid words into new file. Then compare your square into this new *shorter* dictionary.

---

With building up the square, I think there are 2 possibilities to choose between.

1. The first one is to randomly organize the square from the letters and make checks if the letters form up correct words
2. The second one is to randomly choose "correct" words from the dictionary, and write them into your square. After that you check if the words use a correct amount and setting of letters

Comment: I am giving that string as an example but I am trying to keep it open so that I can pass in any string and program attempts to form the word square with given string (provided the length of string and dimension sqrt matches). Thus I let the parameter decide the size of the word square and length of string.

Comment: Well it does not change anything. You get the alphabet by deriving the letters from your parameter string, and you get the word length by measuring the length of your parameter string and taking the square root of it

Comment: Anything that is rejected by rule #1 will also be rejected by rule #3.

Comment: of course, but since the dictionary, or word list is organized alphabetically, it is lucrative to directly discard the words that start with wrong letter

Comment: @SaraSeppola Based on your last sentence, does this falls in line with what you're suggesting. I have reduced my dictionary size to say 50,000. I line up the words for each words for 4 separate ways which would end up with 200,000 possibilities. Each possibility is verified by checking substring values against row and column?

Comment: Well, as I see it, the problem would then be at least reduced? Of course, it is still not optimized and more steps can be taken in the right direction but reducing the problematic is a good way to go, i think :)